# How to extract diagram with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, diagram, bubble-chart

I have an asp.net web project .I do some analysis and extract words out of hypertext and display them in listbox.Here what I want to do is extract a diagram(relational bubble chart).First I thought to keep some bubbles and label inside them.If there are 4 words extracted then I can make the visibility of 4 bubble to true and pass the words to labels but it sounds so simple.Can I use reportviewer for this problem or what else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For charting in ASP.NET Webforms in .NET 4.0 and later, you can use Chart control directly.

For example usage, visit Scott Guthrie blog entry about Chart: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/07/built-in-charting-controls-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx

Comment: actually I am not sure if chart control is useful fr my problem because I need to output something like this http://www.abilitysuccessgrowth.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Bubble-Chart.jpg